# Copy latest file from server to local destination

Tags: powershell

I've been struggling with a script that needs to copy or download the latest file from a file server to the local drive folder. Here is what i came up with:

```
[String]$LocalServer = "\\IP_address\D:\Interfaces\"             
[String]$File_Name = "MK." + (Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyy") + ".tar.gz"  #file name is example MK.040418.tar.gz  
[String]$Path = "C:\Localfolder"                               
[String]$Username = "admin"
[String]$Password = "Admin123"

Copy-Item -Path {$LocalServer + "\" + $FileName} - Destination {$LocalPath}

#$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
#$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password)
#$WebClient.DownloadFile($LocalServer, $FileName)
```

Comment: Is the '$LocalServer' path correct?  looks odd with 'D:' in the middle.  Also, '$LocalPath' doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, and you have a space between the dash and the parameter name in '-Destination'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code:

You don't need to use `{}` to wrap parameters with Powershell.

Your variable is `$File_Name` but you're using `$FileName` (missing `_`) with `Copy-Item` command.

`$LocalServer` ends with a `\`, and you're also adding one in with`$LocalServer + "\" + $FileName`, so the path ends up having a double slash: `\\IP_address\D:\Interfaces\\MK.040418.tar.gz`

Fixing these points, the command should be:

```
Copy-Item -Path "$LocalServer$File_Name" -Destination $LocalPath
```

Comment: Also as boxdog noticed LocalServer looks wrong, you probably want the `D$` admin share: `[String]$LocalServer = "\\IP_address\D$\Interfaces\"`